# Why did the two angels Harut and Marut come to earth?

Tags: quran

As salam Aleikhum friends I want a clarification of why the angels Harut and Marut came to earth what was their role or mission on earth I am reading quran and want to understand better. Thank you Salam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per sunni scholars the famous story which is very commonly related with them is not true and shouldn't be narrated or spread.

Hence it is better to remain noncommittal in this matter

here is whole Verse of Quran  Surah Baqara V 102. 103

And they followed [instead] what the devils had recited during the reign of Solomon. It was not Solomon who disbelieved, but the devils disbelieved, teaching people magic and that which was revealed to the two angels at Babylon, Harut and Marut. But the two angels do not teach anyone unless they say, "We are a trial, so do not disbelieve [by practicing magic]." And [yet] they learn from them that by which they cause separation between a man and his wife. But they do not harm anyone through it except by permission of Allah . And the people learn what harms them and does not benefit them. But the Children of Israel certainly knew that whoever purchased the magic would not have in the Hereafter any share. And wretched is that for which they sold themselves, if they only knew.

Comment: Many scholars say one shouldn't translate the names of a surah.